# Array Values Powershell

Tags: powershell

i wrote a script that works perfect. The code is:

```
[Array] $Services = '1.service','2.serviec','3.service';

# loop through each service, if its running, stop it
foreach($ServiceName in $Services)
{
    $arrService = Get-Service -Name $ServiceName
    write-host $ServiceName
    while ($arrService.Status -eq 'Running')
    {
        Stop-Service $ServiceName
        write-host $arrService.status
        write-host $ServiceName stopping
        Start-Sleep -seconds 60
        $arrService.Refresh()
        if ($arrService.Status -eq 'Stopped')
            {
              Write-Host $ServiceName is now Stopped
            }
     }
 }
```

But I need a script that ask a names service and enter in [Array] $Services = ... I tryed to add this:

```
$Dienst = Read-Host "Please enter the Services"

[Array] $Services = $Dienst

# loop through each service, if its running, stop it
foreach($ServiceName in $Services)
{
    $arrService = Get-Service -Name $ServiceName
    write-host $ServiceName
    while ($arrService.Status -eq 'Running')
    {
        Stop-Service $ServiceName
        write-host $arrService.status
        write-host $ServiceName stopping
        Start-Sleep -seconds 60
        $arrService.Refresh()
        if ($arrService.Status -eq 'Stopped')
            {
              Write-Host $ServiceName is now Stopped
            }
     }
 }
```

When i started the script receive an error

[image: Error - The Services not found]

My Question is - How i can add a different service, which powershell can find in system?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

What [`Read-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/read-host) returns is a *single string*, and if you cast a string to `[Array]` you'll end up with a *single-element* array containing the entire string.

If what is *conceptually* an array (list) is contained in your string, you must construct an array from it yourself, using *text parsing*:

For simplicity, I suggest requiring that the input *not* require embedded quoting (just `foo` instead of `'foo'`) - which assumes that service names don't have embedded *spaces*:

```
# Simulate Read-Host input
$servicesList = 'LAS_LMB, LAS_LWS, LAS_CORE'

# Parse the string input by the user into an array of service names.
$services = -split ($servicesList -replace ',', ' ')
```

Note: The above accepts `,`, whitespace, or a combination of the two as the separator between service names, combining the unary form of the [`-split` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Split) for whitespace-based splitting with the [`-replace` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375) for replacing commas with spaces.

---

Note that `Get-Service`'s `-Name` parameter directly accepts an array of names, so your processing command can be simplified to:

```
Get-Service -Name $services | Where-Object Status -eq Running |
  ForEach-Object {
    Write-Host $_.Name
    do {
        Stop-Service $_.Name
        Write-Host $_.Status
        Write-Host $_.Name stopping
        Start-Sleep -seconds 60
        $_.Refresh()
        if ($_.Status -eq 'Stopped') {
          Write-Host $_.Name is now stopped
        }
     } while ($_.Status -eq 'Running')
 }
```